# Select a random item from json imported dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to select a random player from an imported json file.

```
data = json.loads(source)
randPlayer = data['areas']['homes']
randP = random.choice(randPlayer)

print(randP)
```

Here is a code I tried, basically in 'homes', I have a list of player names and I want to select one at random.

Err Output

[image]

Source Code Example:

{'Player1': {'lvl': 192}, 'Player2': {'lvl': 182}}

Comment: post your output here

Comment: just added the output

Comment: How does `source` look like!  Can you provide an example @BrianNaranjo

Comment: just added the source code I get if I were to print RandPlayer

Comment: I meant the value of the `source` variable!

Comment: So `source={'Player1': {'lvl': 192}, 'Player2': {'lvl': 182}}` ?

Comment: no sorry, source is a big api file that I cant post here completely but once I filter the file in python, the results found in source['homes'] is basically that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
randP = random.choice(list(randPlayer))
```

Comment: Just added the output I'm facing, line 13 israndP = random.choice(randPlayer)

Comment: Can you provide some example values for `source` variable @BrianNaranjo

Answer (score 1):

This is the good example which I found in some other sites, It is giving exact answer and I have checked it already. I am posting this for you and some other people who need perfect answer. All the best

**Example code**

import random

weight_dict = {
  "Kelly": 50,
  "Red": 68,
  "Jhon": 70,
  "Emma" :40
}

key = random.choice(list(weight_dict))

print ("Random key value pair from dictonary is ", key, " - ", weight_dict[key])

**output**

Random key value pair from dictonary is  Jhon  -  70